Stop Steam from opening a second window
When I open Steam, most of the time two windows will open - the “main” Steam window, and then a smaller window that shows a random game that’s popular/has a discount to me.
How can I stop Steam from opening this second window?

As this reddit thread confirms, the method is:
Client's Menu bar at the top: Steam > Settings > Interface > Uncheck "notify me about...." at the bottom.
